# python multithreading: how to ensure a thread is waiting and not currently joining?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a thread A which permanently listens for events. When an event for a particular resource R1 arrives, it starts thread B and passes the job to B for processing. Thread A then continues to listen, while B waits for a job, receives the job from thread A and processes it. Additional events for resources R1 are also sent to thread B (placed in a queue for thread B).  Events for resources R2, R3, and so on are treated similarly, a new thread is started for each unique resource, ie. thread C for R2, thread D for R3, and so on.  The nature of the events is peaky for a particular resource, followed by long periods of nothing, hence thread A starts thread B and when B is finished with the job, it waits for another job from A and if no job arrives, it joins. Because thread B may still be waiting after completing a job from a previous event, thread A checks if B is alive before passing it to the current job (it places it in a queue). If it is still alive, A just passes B the job, if it is not it starts thread B, again and then passes it the job. To ensure serialization of events for a particular resource, only one thread for each resource is started (otherwise this would be trivial, just start a new thread for every event)

Now, here is the problem:  there is a small but finite time when thread B has just timed out waiting for a job and will join, but has not joined, yet. If thread A checks if thread B is alive during that short time, thread A will see that B is alive and send it a job, but B will not process it because it is no longer awaiting jobs - instead it is in the process of joining. Hence the job is not processed.  This can be simulated by inserting a sleep statement as the last line of code in thread B.

How can I ensure that when thread A checks that thread B is alive and is waiting for a job, and not currently joining? I have considered using a lock but acquiring a lock also takes time, even if that time is very small.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want thread B to join again if no job arrives? Why not keep it waiting indefinitely, that certainly solves your issue?

Comment: A side note, you can't join the current thread as it will cause a deadlock but it reads as if you are doing exactly that

Comment: Re, "...and if no job arrives, it joins." Can you explain? Which thread joins which other thread? Or, did you mean to say, it _dies?_ This question would be much improved if you would show us the code instead of trying to describe what it does with words.

Comment: Re, "acquiring a lock also takes time, even if that time is very small." Yes, _very_ small. Too small to be of any significance unless you are using threads for high-performance parallel computations. You said, "...long periods of nothing." OK, so don't be afraid to use a mutex where you need it. And don't try to solve performance problems until you can prove that you _have_ performance problems that need to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

## Use a lock and a flag

The shared state between thread A and thread B looks like this:

```py
lock = Lock()
queue = list()
live = False
```

In thread A, when an event comes in:

```py
with lock:
    if not live:
        spawn_thread_b()
        live = True
    queue.append(event)
```

In thread B, the :

```py
lock.acquire()
while len(queue) > 0:
    events, queue = queue, list() # Swap 'queue' with a new empty list
    lock.release()

    for event in events:
        process(event)

    lock.acquire()

live = False
lock.release()
```

With this implementation, it is possible to have a thread B that is joining while a new thread B is spawned. But it seems to me that this is unavoidable and is actually not an issue because those two threads will not interfere (thanks to the lock).

## Keep threads alive

An alternative solution is to simply keep thread B alive. When no events come in, it will simply wait. Have a look at [condition variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) to implement the waiting for new events.

If you have a huge number of resources and expect the events to be sparsely spread over these resources, then I understand your desire to not keep the threads alive indefinitely.

If you have only a limited number of resources, then maybe keeping threads alive is a more straight-forward approach to tackling your problem. The continuous thread lifetime management is a hassle and may even impact performance in some scenarios.

Comment: I'd recommend making your loop a `while True:` that does `with lock: if not queue: break` (followed by actual swap) at the top, so you can use `with lock:` to protect it, rather than the manual and less reliable explicit `acquire`s and `release`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for the suggestion, is it obvious I have a C++ background? Also, the `if not queue` is a nice shorthand for the emptiness check, thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions but I can't keep threads alive because it won't scale. There are many resources and in many cases very little or no work for many of them, so the threads would just sit there - in my experience cpython start to drown in its own thread management work upwards of ~25 threads.

Comment: @Blindfreddy And does my "Use a lock and flag" approach not solve your issue then?

Comment: As near as I can tell it has the same problem which I am trying to solve: when there are no events in the queue for thread B, the while loop exits and the lock is released. Directly thereafter the lock is reacquired in the final `with lock` block. But in the small but finite time between thread B releasing and reacquiring the lock, thread A may acquire the lock and place another job in the queue, which won't be processed by thread B because is already a zombie and will join after acquiring the lock and setting alive to False.

Comment: @Blindfreddy You are right, in trying to make the code more Pythonic, I seem to have introduced the same issue. Can you check again with my more C++-oriented approach?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis Sure, but I don't quite follow what you mean with C++ approach ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach would work and doesn't require any locks (I used a statemodel to get my head around it)

Thread B has three states:  `alive`, `zombie`, and `dead`. `alive` has two substates, `ready` and `processing`, `zombie` also has two substates, `draining`, and `drained`. The key to the whole thing is to realize that nothing can stop thread B from becoming a zombie because it will simply time out independently from thread A. So there must be a mechanism for thread A to check if thread B has become a zombie and not send it any more jobs. Here is how I think it could work:  once thread B is a zombie (ie it has timed out waiting for a job), it will definitely join so thread A must not send it any more jobs. So when thread B times out it must update its state to `zombie`, check if there are any more jobs (that's the substate `zombie::draining`) that thread A may have put just after thread B timed out, churn through them and when there are no more jobs enter substate `zombie::drained` and join.  At that point its superstate will change to `dead`, ie the `is_alive` method will return `False`.

So thread B starts its life in the state `alive::ready` when thread A creates it.  It then waits for a job from thread A and when a job arrives it enters state `alive::processing`. It processes it and returns to state `alive::ready`. That continues until eventually thread A does not have any more jobs within the the timeout period, thread B then times out and enters state `zombie`.

Now, every time thread A receives and event, it checks the state of thread B: if it  is in state `dead` (or has never been started), it starts it. If it is in state `alive` it simply sends it the job. Finally, if  it is in state `zombie` it stops sending it jobs and waits (polls) until it is in state `dead`, which means it has completed all pending jobs. Thread A can now be certain that there is no running thread B so it simply starts a new instance of thread B and sends it the pending job(s).

The only downside I can think of in this model is that thread A must check thread B's state every time it gets an event for B and that thread A must wait for B to complete when it is in state `zombie` and start a new instance of thread B. But the whole thing is very unlikely to occur in the first place because the time window is really small when thread A checks and places a job and thread B is practially simultaneously timing out.